# Post-Build Event in VS2012 with NodeJS/GulpJS Code 255 on Publish

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, gulp, durandal-2.0

I'm trying to get a pre-build event setup in visual studio 2012 for compressing my Durandaljs app using Gulp.  After much frustration with the pre/post build command line I have it working if I build the project.  It runs node/gulp as expected.

My issue now is when I goto publish my project using the publish dialog (web deploy) the command fails with **"exited with code 255."** along with first alerting **"Server was unexpected at this time."**  I'm having trouble finding much information on this error combination and I don't know what else to try.

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release ( 
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "$(ProjectDir)node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js" --gulpfile "$(ProjectDir)gulpfile.js" --cwd "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName" --no-color durandal
    )
```

Edit:  I've reduced the issue down further.  It has nothing to do with Gulp, rather it is something with node running from the build command line.  I am running a simple helloworld.js file piped into node and it is the same behavior.  It works fine on build, however, on publish it gives the same errors.

Comment: Check if you are using a variable called "Server" that was not defined. The error looks similar to a var_not_defined error in batch scripts

Comment: Open up a command prompt, and run gulp from your project directory.  I know it's extra layers of abstraction, but I tend to simply pass the projectdir and configurationname to a batch file, then run from there, or call into npm.  I'm guessing it's an issue with your script.